# Error with Chemgreek

Tags: errors

I have windows 8.1 pro with texworks and miktex when I run the template I have, I got error with chemgreek file. when I installed texlive I run it without error

```
Undefined control sequence. \chemgreek_drop_symbols:
any help to use miktex?
```

Comment: This looks a *lot* like http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/248937/ Are you sure the error is about `\chemgreek_drop_symbols:` being undefined? I rather suspect it's `\str_case_upper:f` which is undefined and which would mean that you'd need to update your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem. I suppose `chemgreek` is missing in the package from the repository.

So to circumvent the problem, I've dowload manually `chemgreek.sty` and put it in `MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\chemmacros` and refresh FNDB afterwards.

Hope it can help you

Comment: `\chemgreek_drop_symbols:` is only defined *and* used in `chemgreek.sty`. A missing `chemgreek` can't possibly be the reason for the error!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I loaded `textgreek` together with `chemgreek` and the problem disappeared.