# chemgreek.sty error with achemso

Tags: packages, achemso

I am trying to use achemso packages donwloaded directly from CTAN. Although I have installed the packages to the location MiXTex2.9/tex/latex, I have an error message saying that 'File `chemgreek.sty' not found'. I have texmaker as a tex editor and tried to add  the .sty file manually to the macros as suggested before [Error with Chemgreek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249002/error-with-chemgreek), but that did not work either. What would you think that my problem is?

Comment: Please install packages using the MikTeX package manager.

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion. I removed the achemso package that I installed before and reinstalled via MixTex package manager and refresh FNDB, but that is still not working. I do not know what I am missing.

Comment: The package manager should take care of installing the package, all dependencies and also refreshing the database without user interaction. What is not working? Is it still that `chemgreek` is not found? or a different issue?

Comment: Yes, the same error 'File `chemgreek.sty' not found' was appeared. So, I simply uncommanded the package {mhchem} which includes chemgreek.sty file and my document does not really need that packages, the template is compiled without any error. However, when I add my .bib file, another error "! Paragraph ended before \@BOOKMARK was complete" I am having. I can not figure out what is the relation between my .bib file and \@BOOKMARK and could not find any item in the group. Would you have any comment or suggestion for this error?

Comment: mhchem is only needed for chemistry in the document. Regarding the bookmarks, i suggest to open a new question with a [MWE](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) so helpers can reproduce your problem. Extremely helpful to have one, as no guesswork is going on.

Comment: Out of interest: Where can i find the template? `achemso` is for submissions to the american chemical society, and *nothing* more.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: The template called 'achemso-demo.tex' is provided by JACS. The website is 'http://www.latextemplates.com/template/acs-publications'.

Comment: @EsmaEryilmaz No, it's provided by _me_ as part of the `achemso` bundle!

Comment: @JosephWright, Yes, my apologies! http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/achemso.

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to tell your MikTeX where to find chemgreek.sty.  You'll want to make your own local texmf directory, put chemgreek.sty in it, then tell MikTeX where that directory is.  Follow the instructions from this post:

[Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex)

with the links listed there as a guide.

Comment: Could you be more precise about what "tell your MikTeX where to find it" means? The trick with command-line stuff is that you have to be clear and precise, or it won't work, so could you be more specific?